# Using JavaScript and CSS to create hovers and onclicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have 4 thumbnail images on the bottom of my page with a main, large image above it. I want to be able to click the thumbnail and have it load into the big image. Additionally, I want to be able to hover over the thumbnail and have a black border appear around it.

I have 40 pages that have the exact same setup (4 thumbs, 1 main image) but all different images (products). The thumbs are all in `class="bottom-pic`".

It seems easy enough, but perhaps I'm wrong. I'm thinking CSS for the hover, JS for the clicking? I'm VERY new to JS.

Here is the source code:

```
<a href=""img src="images-large/cobra-dark-wood.jpg" alt="" id="main-photo" >

<img src="images-large/cobra-dark-wood.jpg" alt="" name="photo-bottom-one"  class="bottom-pic" id="photo-bottom-one">

<img src="images-large/cobra-dark-wood-one.jpg" alt="" id="photo-bottom-two"  class="bottom-pic">

<img src="images-large/cobra-black.jpg" alt="" id="photo-bottom-three"  class="bottom-pic">

<img src="images-large/cobra-black-one.jpg" alt="" name="photo-bottom-four"  class="bottom-pic" id="photo-bottom-four">
```

Comment: check again your code `<a href=""img src="...` is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, and not requiring anchor tags etc, here is the JavaScript you could use.

**NB:** This examples assumes you are using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.bottom-pic').on('click', function(){
        $('.bottom-pic').removeClass("active"); //Removes class from all items
        $(this).addClass("active");  //Adds class only to the currently clicked on item
        $('#main-photo').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')); //Changes the source of the image tag
    });
});
```

To see a working demo, I created this fiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZgjR/

Please note that the images don't match up because they are being dynamically loaded from a server, but the effect is exactly what you're asking for, just use this code with your images!

I also added an "active" style if you want the border to stay on the item you've clicked on. Simply add some CSS to the style `.active { }`

Hope this helps

Comment: Life. Saver. Exactly what I needed! Got the border hover working. As for jQuery, I've downloaded the latest jQuery file, placed it in my working folder, and put the src in the head tag. But nothing happens when I click my thumbs.

Comment: Ok, make sure you wrap the JavaScript code in the $(document).ready() function - I edited my answer to show you

Comment: +1 for the ready function. @user3440207: if you found an answer helpful you should show your appreciation by up-voting / accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would use CSS for the border on hover. You may have to use `box-sizing: border-box` to make sure things don't jump around a bunch.

First, your main image should be something like this:

```
<a href="whatever_link"> 
    <img src="images-large/cobra-dark-wood.jpg" alt="" id="main-photo">
</a>
```

Since you're using jQuery, it would be easy enough to get the switch out the source of the main image on click. Something like this:

```
$('.bottom-pic').on('click', function(){
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#main-photo').attr('src', imgSrc);
});
```

That's just off the top of my head. I haven't tested it.

Comment: Just looking at the original code again in my source code. There is no <a href"> at all. Do I need it? If so, what am I even linking to? I don't need to be able to click the main-photo, only the thumbs.

Comment: No you don't need it. I just figured it was there because you wanted to link to something.